# How to vertically align image in a td cell, without vertically-align

Tags: css, alignment, html-table, vertical-alignment

Following code:

```
<div id="test">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="img1.jpg" />
          <p>Bla bla bla</p>
          <p><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#test td {
    width: 450px;
    height: 220px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 50px solid #fff;
}

#test td p {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 290px;
}

#test img {
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

How can I align the second image with the link to the bottom of the cell? I was googling a lot but none of the solutions work for me...

Comment: you can use two row and two of them valign to top it will be like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the container (`td`) `position: relative` and the image, or more specifically the `<p>` which contains the image, `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. [See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsgt8/).

Comment: `position: relative` loose my cells border :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td valign="top">
          <img src="img1.jpg" />
          <p>Bla bla bla</p>
          <p><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></p>
        </td>
```

Comment: I think did not make myself clear. I want the content to be vertically aligned to the top but the last image, the img2.jpg, aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<p>Bla bla bla</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></p>
```

And this CSS:

```
#test td {
    width: 450px;
    height: 220px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 50px solid #fff;
}

#test td p {
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
}

#test img {
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/maWJ2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left;` from `#test img`

```
#test img {
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/456Zz/)**